# Best combination of multiple list by picking only one value per list

Tags: java

I've multiple lists and would like to find the best combination by picking only 1 value from each list. The best combination is where the total value is the highest. e.g.:

In the table below the idea combination would be event 1 from person 2, event 2 from person 3 and event 3 from person 1. Please note that this is an example and that the number of 'events' and 'persons' may vary.

| Person | Event 1 | Event 2 | Event 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person 1 | 5 | 2 | 6 |
| Person 2 | 10 | 3 | 6 |
| Person 3 | 1 | 7 | 2 |

The best combination would be:

- Person 1: Event 3 (6)
- Person 2: Event 1 (10)
- Person 3: Event 2 (7)

I first thought that this could be achieved with the Cartesian Product. For more details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product. However that will only sum all combination and don't take the 'pick-only-one-value-from-each-list' into account.

```
private static List<Integer> listOfPerson1 = List.of(5, 2, 6);
private static List<Integer> listOfPerson2 = List.of(10, 3, 6);
private static List<Integer> listOfPerson3 = List.of(1, 7, 2);


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> listOfPersons = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfPersons.add(listOfPerson1);
    listOfPersons.add(listOfPerson2);
    listOfPersons.add(listOfPerson3);

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    generatePermutations(listOfPersons, result, 0, 0);

    for (Integer i : result) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

static void generatePermutations(List<List<Integer>> lists, List<Integer> result, int depth, Integer current) {
    if (depth == lists.size()) {
        result.add(current);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < lists.get(depth).size(); i++) {
        generatePermutations(lists, result, depth + 1, current + lists.get(depth).get(i));
    }
}
```

Any idea how this can be achieved or what the name of such algorithm/mathematics is?

Comment: do i missed it or you have not explained what is the "best combination"?

Comment: Is is just the greatest integer in each row?

Comment: Can you show some code you have tried?  Please add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question as I agree it was unclear. I'm looking for the best combination by picking only 1 value from each list. The best combination is where the total value is the highest. I thought that this could be achieved by using the Cartesian Product (see code example) but that will make a combination of all possibilities while it's only allowed to pick one of each list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is actually called the *Assignment Problem* which involves assigning agents to tasks in a way that optimises the total cost incurred.

In terms of algorithms to solve it, the one that I have seen used the most is the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) (also the pioneering algorithm for this problem) which has polynomial time complexity.

Comment: Thanks @Henry Twist, just had a quick look and see that this is looking for the best solution where the outcome should be as low/cheap as possible. However based on this algorithm it should be possible to do the inverse, thanks!

Comment: Yes definitely, you could either adapt the algorithm or just use negative numbers! Good luck!

Comment: Use of negative numbers is perhaps not a nice way to fix it, but it's working :).